# Is there a way to change the way geometry is drawn in Three.js?

Tags: three.js

I'm new to WebGL and OpenGL. I've worked with an OpenGL library elsewhere that gives me the options of choosing how my geometry is "drawn". For example I can select triangles, quads, line_loop, points, etc.

My question is: based on my research so far, Three.js removed the option for quads due to rendering issues. Are there any other options on how geometric shapes are drawn?

Here's a graph depicting what I mean: http://www.opentk.com/files/tmp/persistent/opentk/files/GeometricPrimitiveTypes.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polygons and Quads are pretty much useless, because your typical rasterizer (software or GPU) can deal only with convex, coplanar primitives. It's easy to construct a quad or polygon that's concave or not coplanar or both. Hence quads and polygons have been removed from modern OpenGL. Triangles, in any form are safe though, there's no way for a triangle to be concave or not coplanar.

Comment: What about the other examples listed here?
http://www.opentk.com/files/tmp/persistent/opentk/files/GeometricPrimitiveTypes.gif

Comment: @rpeg: triangle strips and fans are no problem, because the GPU will only see the individual triangles for rasterization (geometry and tesselation shaders "see" the strip or fan, but those don't care about it, because they only care about the vertices and not the filling). Line strips and loops are no problem either as are points. In short: Everything that can be broken down unabiguously into triangles, simple lines or points is no problem. Quads and polygons can not be broken down unambiguously hence they got removed.